# Look up array of values as the value of a key of a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
dic = {'Mr A':[1200,1500,1100], 'Mr B':[2200, 3000, 1200]}
```

and I want to look up a value from the array of values to get keys which satisfy the query.

I tried this,

```
>>> 1200 in dic.values()
False
```

I get a match only when I look up the entire array.

```
>>> [1200,1500,1100] in dic.values()
True
```

How do I look inside the arrays and get the keys which match the query?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using list comprehension:

```
>>> dic = {'Mr A':[1200,1500,1100], 'Mr B':[2200, 3000, 1200]}
>>> [key for key, value in dic.iteritems() if 1200 in value]
['Mr A', 'Mr B']
>>> [key for key, value in dic.iteritems() if 3000 in value]
['Mr B']
```

Answer (score 0):

`dic.values()` returns `[[1200, 1500, 1100], [2200, 3000, 1200]]` which is a list of lists.

`a in b` evaluates to `True` only when one or more of the elements of `b` is equal to `a`.

So of course `1200` is not `in` `dic.values()` because:

`1200 != [1200, 1500, 1100]`

and

`1200 != [2200, 3000, 1200]`.

If you want to see if `1200` is in any of the sublists, you can:

```
import itertools 
1200 in itertools.chain(*dic.values())
```

See: http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain for details for `itertools.chain`

If you actually want to know which key the list in which your element appears belongs to you can:

```
[k for k, v in dic.items() if elem in v]
```

where you would first set `elem` to the value you are searching for (such as `1200`).

This should return a list of all the keys that are associated with a list that contains your value.